# Pandas TimeStamp type is not recognized by pyright

Tags: python, pandas, python-typing, pyright

I have a segment of code that looks at a pandas' DataFrame column that's a Series of Timestamps and requests the date for the Timestamp. When I run pyright over this code it returns an error saying that it `Cannot access the member "date" for type "[type]"\nMember "date" is unknown` none of the types listed is a Timestamp type.
Here's an example of the code.

```py
def foo_function(foobar: pandas.DataFrame):
    foo = foo_bar.loc[index, "date_time_column"].date()
```

It's pretty simple, the DataFrame supplied has a "date_time_column". In the debugger referencing the value with the index and column returns a value of type Timestamp and the column series has a `datetime64` dtype.
It's also worth noting that using `assert isinstance(foo_bar.loc[index, "date_time_column"], pd.Timestamp)`  before calling `.date()` doesn't resolve this as expected. I still get errors for other possible types in the DataFrame such as

```
error: Cannot access member "date" for type "complex"
    Member "date" is unknown (reportGeneralTypeIssues)
```

```
error: Cannot access member "date" for type "Timedelta"
    Member "date" is unknown (reportGeneralTypeIssues)
```

etc.

Comment: It would be best if you could provide a minimum reproducible example for the pyright error you are describing.

Comment: @ringo I updated the question with more details. Please let me know if there are other questions.

Comment: How do you expect a static type checker to know the data type of _some_ column in _some_ `DataFrame`?

Comment: Even if it _were_ possible have a dataframe with that kind of type-awareness. All you are doing here is telling the type checker that `foobar` is _any_ `DataFrame`. It has _no way of knowing_ what the specific types of its columns are.